# Auto-generate forms based on list entries

Tags: list, workflow, powershell, form

I work for an MSP, where I am creating a process in SharePoint 2013 Enterprise to assist in "onboarding" our customers. We have a SharePoint list populated with some best practices and things to look for when going through the onboarding process. I would like to auto-populate some input forms based on the questions in the SharePoint "Master Standards List", and allow the entries from the forms to go into other SharePoint lists. That data will later be used as documentation for our support engineers, reports showing the customers, sales opportunities, among other things.

My issue currently is that I would like to auto-generate the forms based on the "Master Standards List" to create the questions for the different stages of onboarding and best practices implementation. I understand that I can probably go through and manually create the forms from the list of questions, but I expect our list to grow over time so I would like to not have to keep manually updating the forms each time a question is added/changed/removed.

I have created a diagram explaining how I would like the process to work and would like it to be as automated as possible.

[image: Best Practices Diagram]

I have attempted to use InfoPath and SharePoint Designer, but have not found a way to auto-generate the forms. I have thought that maybe I could use PowerShell or an external resource to create the forms and then put the data back into the other SharePoint lists but was thinking there had to be a way that someone has used before.

Any assistance in getting this part sorted out would be greatly appreciated.